# Do google data studio save thumbnail in actual file or their link just returns PNG? and if so, how can we do the same?

Tags: httpserver

I have noticed that Google data studio uses a link as thumbnail (https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/6a62f183-0dec-4639-aa70-83de742c2872/page/GHUzB/thumbnail), which does not end in .png but result is a PNG file. I suspect that actual PNG may not even exist and it is being generated like a base64 image is generated. I may be wrong but if I am right, I want to understand how they are doing it so that I can do the same. It will solve a huge problem I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP clients does not differs files based on extensions, but according to [MIME types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type).

In short, the extension is not really relevant when transferring files over the internet.  If you set the [Content-Type header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) to `image/png` in a HTTP response and insert a PNG file information in the body, you'll get the same result.

**Base64** is completely another topic.  It is related to how the file content is encoded (useful to describe binary data in plain text), and you should NOT use in this case.  The HTTP body should contain the PNG image in its original binary format.